# Can't have break outside of loop (even though it is in a loop!)

Tags: jquery, each, break

I'm trying to break out of a loop if a certain condition is true. My code works fine until I try and add the break in. The intellisense error in VS2010 and IE8 when running both tell me I cant break outside of a loop, but I don't think I am.

I'm totally confused so hoping someone can point out something obvious I'm overlooking!

```
var value1 = "hello"; 

$.each(myJsonObject.SomeCollection, function () {

    if (value1 == this.value2) {
        alert("Found it!");
        exitFlag = true;
    }

    if (exitFlag) break;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery might not be using a loop for the `.each()` function. Maybe returning `false` might work (in Python it does):

```
var value1 = "hello"; 

$.each(myJsonObject.SomeCollection, function () {

    if (value1 == this.value2) {
        alert("Found it!");
        exitFlag = true;
    }

    if (exitFlag) return false;
});
```

Comment: I'd opt to make it simpler by returning right after the call to `alert()` as the `exitFlag` variable does not add any value to the structure of the sample code.

Comment: You cant return from the loop within the if statement though can you

Answer (score 1):

Simply `return false;` to exit the `.each` loop. [From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a
>   particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return `false`.
>   Returning *non-false* is the same as a
>   `continue` statement in a for loop; it
>   will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Using the jQuery `.each` iterator is not the same as using a regular loop, so `break` cannot be used here. It would be like doing this, which is impossible:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  myFunc(i);
}

function myFunc(i) {
  if (i > 5) {
    break; // ILLEGAL
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that first and it gave me a similar problem - will try this again later though, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your collection can be treated, navigated and indexed like an array, just use a regular loop and break from it. Or if you are so bent in using the `$.each` iterator for such a simple thing, then just have your function return false (which will effectively make the `$.each` iterator stop).

And to re-enforce what I just said, if that collection can be treated as an array, just use a plain loop. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, always use the simplest, cleanest tool to get the job done.